# What is the 'etc' ruby gem for?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I was looking through some code and came across a "require 'etc'" line.  Of course, googling for things like "ruby etc gem" has been fruitless.  I haven't found any documentation for it (yet) so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't assume that just because something has a "boring" sounding name like `etc` that it's safe to delete the folder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know it's a gem, you should search from http://rubygems.org/, which immediately leads to http://rubygems.org/gems/etc.

The [source code](http://codeforpeople.com/lib/ruby/etc/etc-0.2.0/lib/etc.rb) shows it's a parser of [`/etc/passwd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd_%28file%29) and `/etc/group`.

Answer (score 6):

While @KennyTM's answer is generally correct, in this particular case, the 'etc' it's referring to is almost certainly the `etc` from the standard library, and not the gem. They do similar things, but the stdlib one is an interface to the `getpw*` and `getgr*` system calls (among other things), and perusing the code or documentation of the 'etc' gem would probably lead to confusion.

The documentation for the stdlib `etc` may be found on [the ruby-doc site](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/etc/rdoc/index.html), among others.